# Extract specific data from json to display them in html

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

first of all, i would like to warn you i m  a fresh beginner and trying to  solve my problem by searching everywhere but without success.

I try to pick data from a json result:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>mysql data test</title>
</head>
<script src="http://mysqljs.com/mysql.js"></script>
<body>
<pre id="result"></pre>
<script>
MySql.Execute(
    "host",
    "user", 
    "pass", 
    "base", 
    "select * from congel where code ='1000000000001'", 
    function (data) {
var resultat = JSON.stringify(data);
});
 // document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultat; 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

once the resultat var is displayed, i obtain :

```
{"Success":true,"Result":[{"id":1,"produit":"accra de morue","quantite":8,"localisation":"B7","code":1000000000001}]}
```

i tryed to extract the data such as

```
var produit = resultat.Result.produit
```

etc but nothing is display, i tryed another way

```
var i, x="";
for (i in resultat.Result) {
x = resultat.Result[i].produit;    
}
```

still doesnt work, some help would be really appreaciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like this :

```
var i, x="";

for (i in resultat.Result) {
   x = i.produit;    
}
```

because `i` is an object

or you can do that :

```
var i, x="";

for (i = 0; i < resultat.Result.length; i++) { 
    x = resultat.Result[i].produit;   
}
```